# One over two buttons working for a android app

Tags: java, android

So I´m trying to code an app with 2 buttons.I´m following a tutorial but is complicated to understand.

So well my intention is very simple:
One button heads to one receipe and the other one to a different one.

The first button works but the second one gives me an error and closes the app. would you help me? I´m a begginer with Android.

Second question what is the purpose of OnCreateOptionsMenu and OnOptionsItemSelected?

```
package com.example.miapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
//added

import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;



        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        Button button1;
        Button button2;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //enable back button in the top action bar
            //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



                 button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
                 button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 


                 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
                 button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Context context = this;

              switch (v.getId()) {
                 case R.id.button1: 
                  // do something
                     Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, PaellaActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent1);
                  break;
                 case R.id.button2:
                  // do something else
                     Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, BandaActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent2);
                  break;
              }
           }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }




        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

    //      
    //      switch (item.getItemId()) {
    //        case android.R.id.home:
    //        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    //        return true;
    //     }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which error getting on second Button Click?

Comment: Do edit the question with the error you obtain in `logcat` if you need help from the community. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you didn't initialise your activity of the one failing in your AndroidManifest.xml using

```
<Activity name="location.of.your.activity"/>
```

Comment: Oh thanks Mo Adel, you were right I didn´t initialize them and now works. About this can u guys tell me something: Second question what is the purpose of OnCreateOptionsMenu and OnOptionsItemSelected?

Comment: If i answered your question, please tick it as the correct answer so it can help other. to answer your question onCreateOptionMenu should inflate the menu at the top of the activity in the actionbar, OnOptionsItemSelected handles clicks on the menu item